# Error On Build after updating mediasoup-client to v3.6.46 and Above Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, mediasoup

I was using **mediasoup-client 3.6.16** and have updated to the latest version **3.6.57**.
After updating I am not able to build. Using webpack (**v2.4.1**) to build.

***Dependencies:***

- Node: v16.13.2
- NPM: 8.1.2
- React: 16.8.4
- React-Dom: 16.8.4
- Webpack: 2.4.1
- babel-core: 6.2.1
- babel-loader: 6.2.0
- babel-preset-es2015: 6.1.18
- babel-preset-react": 6.1.18
- babel-polyfill: 6.26.0

Getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/mediasoup-client/lib/handlers/Chrome74.js
Module parse failed: /home/notabot/Downloads/broadcasting_project/node_modules/mediasoup-client/lib/handlers/Chrome74.js Unexpected token (132:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             rtcpMuxPolicy: 'require',
|             sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan',
|             ...additionalSettings
|         }, proprietaryConstraints);
|         // Handle RTCPeerConnection connection status.
 @ ./~/mediasoup-client/lib/Device.js 34:19-49
 @ ./~/mediasoup-client/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/components/page/assistant/assistant-main.js
 @ ./src/components/page/teacher/app.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./src/index.js babel-polyfill
```

The need for updating the **mediasoup-client** was using the feature **profile-level-id**
Thus updated to the latest version, however, as soon as I updated to v3.6.57 and made **no change to code**, and tried to build it **fails**.

Then tried backtracking and found that after version **v3.6.45** I am not able to create the build.

Just wanted to know what I am doing wrong that has resulted in an issue when I am creating the build and how to correct it?

***Additions Information:***

Importing format: ***import { Device } from "mediasoup-client"***

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js',
    'babel-polyfill'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: './',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
 ]
};
```

Comment: I saw one other question that was similar and the mediasoup devs said to check your node version - what version are you on?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing  Node v16.13.2 and I also read that article in which the dev said to update node / use latest Node version, but I have tried everything nothing works for me.

Comment: If you don't need the latest update, you can downgrade the package to the working version you had earlier.  isn't that also working?

Comment: @kavigun The business requirement is there where I need at least a version  **3.6.50+**